# Magento (v 1.7.0.2) - Add "Shipping Method" column in Sales Order Grid

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add a new column for Shipping Method (Standard, Priority, Express) in the Sales Order Grid located here:

/home/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

I've researched tons of methods but either it's for an older version of magento, or simply doesn't work. From what I understand, I need to do the following:

1. Edit _prepareCollection()
2. Add a case in _prepareColumns() like the following:

`$this->addColumn('shipping_description', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Method'),
            'index' => 'shipping_description',
        ));`

Can someone please help me get this figured out?

Answer (score 2):

For adding shipping info into sales order grid  You have to override  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid class. For this create your own module.
=> In config.xml 
   in block section
   paste below xml code

```
<globals>
    <block>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>Yourpackage_Yourmodule_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </block>
<globals>
```

Now define a class Yourpackage_Yourmodule_Block_Sales_Order_Grid and put it into 
package_name/module_name/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

```
class Yourpackage_Yourmodule_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{
protected function _prepareCollection()
{

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->
    joinLeft('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id=sales_flat_order.entity_id', array("shipping_desc"=>"shipping_description"));

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return $this;
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumnAfter('shipping_desc', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Descr #'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'shipping_desc',
    ),"real_order_id");
    return parent::_prepareColumns();

}

}
```

Comment: Simple answer, your solution doesn't work. There are a lot of issues, such as sorting by column, order status, or really any type of filtering. It throws tons of errors.  I've resorted to hiring a programmer to build a tried & tested module.

Comment: For anyone finding this and hoping for a solution, simply change "return $this" to "return parent::_prepareCollection()" et voila

Answer (score 0):

I am still looking for a good solution myself. But as an approach I would like to contribute my knowledge so far based on Magento 1.7

- I prefer use of `setCollection` instead of `_prepareCollection()`. It seems there are less problems with filtering etc. when using `setCollection`
- The perfect attribute is so close yet so far. shipping_description can be found in `sales_order_flat`. Unfortunately the default collection is based upon `sales_flat_order_grid`.
  One possible solution is to switch this by overwriting `_getCollectionClass`

  ```
  protected function _getCollectionClass()
  {
      //return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
      return 'sales/order_collection';
  }
  ```

  It's important to say that this leads to other problems. E.g. shipping name and billing name are empty because they got their info from `sales_flat_order_grid`. We could get them from `sales_flat_order_address` but I am not sure if this leads to far away from a good solution...
- Another approach is to join with `sales_order_flat`. This way we keep all information from `sales_flat_order_grid` and also can get the `shipping_method`. Problem here is a count(*) statement that occurs while filtering. The error is about an ambigious `increment_id`. At the moment I think it is a Magento bug because `increment_id` should not be used without conjunction to its table.
- Not to forget a third way: We could extend `saled_flat_order_grid` and add `shipping_method`, but I think that would be way to harsh. Dont't touch `app/code/core` und the tables as long as nobody stands behind you with a gun in his hands ;-)

So far I am still undecided which way to go. Perhaps there is another (better) way that I didn't list here?

Answer (score 0):

This extension should give you a very quick, easy solution to your problem
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/OSdave/extension/5814/orders_grid_payment_shipping_filters

Comment: Please post more than just a link.